# Changing the Default Multicast Address in Wildfly

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

As described in the doc: [Controlling the Default Multicast Address with -u](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command+line+parameters#Commandlineparameters-defaultmulticastaddress).  I changed the default multicast address in my Wildfly server from:

```
standalone.bat -u=230.12.345.67
```

to placing it inside the config file standalone.xml.  I added this to the system property:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="jboss.default.multicast.address" value="230.12.345.67"/>
</system-properties>
```

Which should be picked up by the socket-binding-group:

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
...
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
```

However, it seems to be ignored and defaults to 230.0.0.4.